# Page not loading until refresh

Tags: php, jquery

i'm having a little problem on a website:
Some of the pages doesn't load automatically when reached after clicking on a link.
For example if i go directly to this page http://www.micheleferrotti.it/photo_shop.php?id=1 it works properly but if i click of the "SHOP" http://www.micheleferrotti.it/ it shows a grey empty page until i perform a page refresh.
Coa someone help me to understand where is the issue?

Please consider that php script in the page only generate image boxes and if it can be usefull i'm attaching it here below:

```
$files = glob("images/photo_shop/$id_catalogo/*.*");
echo '<div id="img_row">';
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $num = $files[$i];
    $cleanName = str_replace("images/photo_shop/$id_catalogo/","",$num);
    if ($i > 0 and $i % 6 == 0) {
        echo '</div><div id="img_row">';
    }
    echo '<div class="img_box" id="img_box">
              <a href="'. $num .'" rel="lightbox" title="'.$cleanName.'">
                  <img src="'.$num.'" alt="'.$num.'" width="120px" height="120px" style="padding:2px" />
              </a>
              <a href="'.$cleanName.'" class="over_img buy white">
                  COMPRA FOTO
              </a>
          </div>';  
}
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Several js files are 404ing on the page, which may be the source of some unexpected behavior. Also, it looks like you're loading an awful lot of images all at once. Is paginating an option?

Comment: You should **really** generate thumbnails for the images instead of just using the big 1-2MB images as thumbnails. Might be that's why it takes so long to load.

Comment: Just a hint: for long strings, you might want to consider using HEREDOC syntax. It's way more readable.

Comment: Thanks jameslafferty i will check the js files!
Yes jCuber you are right, i'm working on the resize script and for this reason the thumbnails are not still present.
Thanks Johannes H i will consider performing the changes as suggested using HEREDOC.